# Bypass windows file assignation reset

Tags: c#, winforms

i am developing a music player in C# winforms.
My program has code which sets the .mp3 files deafult app to my program.

The code works but everytime it runs, windows resets the app:

[image: screenshot]

(dont mind the extension in the image i got it from the internet cuz i wasnt able to screenshot it on my pc)

Is there a way to bypass this reset?

Comment: The error says that your application had a problem. You need to identify and fix that problem, not try to force the user to use a faulty application

Comment: My application is not the problem because it work okay on a custom file extensions. It also uses '.streamer' files (custom) which are assigned without any errors.

Comment: Did you check the Windows Event Log to see if there are any errors?

Comment: yes, there are none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Windows 10, you cannot change the default application of a file type programmatically. The user is meant to change by himself the default programs from and only from the OS.

You can see the "Important" note in the MS doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/shell/default-programs?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: oh, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the help anyways